# Convert UTF8 to Boolean in Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the best way to convert a column with dtype utf8 that contains "true" and "false" values to dtype Boolean?

### map_dict

This solution works

```bash
df.with_column(
    pl.col("bool_col").map_dict({"false":False, "true":True})
)
```

### direct cast

```bash
df["bool_col"].cast(pl.Boolean).unique()
```

Leads to

```
ArrowErrorException: NotYetImplemented("Casting from LargeUtf8 to Boolean not supported")
```

### indirect cast

The idea is to go via the Categorical dtype.
But this leads to only True values

```bash
print(df["bool_col"].unique())
print(df["bool_col"].cast(pl.Categorical).unique())
print(df["bool_col"].cast(pl.Categorical).cast(pl.Boolean).unique())
```

```
shape: (2,)
Series: 'sensorvalue' [str]
[
    "true"
    "false"
]
shape: (2,)
Series: 'sensorvalue' [cat]
[
    "false"
    "true"
]
shape: (1,)
Series: 'sensorvalue' [bool]
[
    true
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just compare with the `'true'` literal?

```py
In [42]: df = pl.DataFrame({'sensorvalue': ['true', 'false', 'true']})

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ sensorvalue │
│ ---         │
│ str         │
╞═════════════╡
│ true        │
│ false       │
│ true        │
└─────────────┘

In [44]: df.with_columns(pl.col('sensorvalue')=='true')
Out[44]:
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────┐
│ sensorvalue │
│ ---         │
│ bool        │
╞═════════════╡
│ true        │
│ false       │
│ true        │
└─────────────┘
```

### EDIT

better solution (which propagates nulls):

```
In [8]: df.with_columns(
   ...:     pl.col("sensorvalue").map_dict({"false":False, "true":True})
   ...: )
```

Comment: not sure about null values with this approach though...those will be converted to false I guess?